# What the probability that the door will be operational at any point in time?

Tags: probability

An aircraft door has 3 components a mechanical system and a hydraulic system, which need to work in tandem for the door to operate, and in case the
above system fails, there is also an electronic controller that can operate the door all by itself. The chances that the mechanical system the hydraulic
system and the electronic controller work properly are 90% 80% and 95% respectively.

a. 0.014
b. 0.760
c. 0.916
d. 0.986

I tried (1-0.1*0.2*0.05=0.999) but this is not matching with the answer, I don't know what I am missing

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: Can you compute the probability that the mechanical system opens the door? Can you at least indicate what you think the answer might be (I mean, you have "almost never" and "almost always" as options - hopefully at least one of these strikes you as unreasonable, especially given how often the electric system alone suffices?)

Comment: This is an aptitude question with all the information. I tried  (1-0.1*0.2*0.05=0.999) but this is not matching with the answer, I don't know what I am missing

Comment: That is something that should have been included in the body of your post.

Answer (score 1):

It's not stated, but I'll assume that the chances of each component failing are independent.

The chance that both the mechanical and the hydraulic systems work is $72 \%$.  Therefore, the chance that at least one of them fails, preventing you from using that tandem to open the door, is $28 \%$.  The chance that the electronic system fails is $5 \%$.  Therefore, the chance that you can't open the door is $1.4 \%$ so the chance that you will be able to open the door is $0.986$.